# python on linux can't understand sql timestamps

Tags: python, linux, timestamp, db2, pyodbc

I have a simple query that runs perfectly using python on windows.

```
import pandas as pd
... # database connection omitted
pd.read_sql("select * from table where time_stamp >= '2018-6-11'", conn)
```

But on my Linux machine, it gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_data.py", line 16, in <module>
    df = pd.read_sql(extract, conn)
  File "/home/jm/anaconda3/envs/s1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 381, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/home/jm/anaconda3/envs/s1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1422, in read_query
    data = self._fetchall_as_list(cursor)
  File "/home/jm/anaconda3/envs/s1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1431, in _fetchall_as_list
    result = cur.fetchall()
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

Any idea what could cause this? I've updated anaconda and pandas and pyodbc which is what I'm using to make the connection on both machines.

I've also made sure the connection to the database is working great on both machines.

It only has problems on that date string, which it converts easily to a timestamp when running on windows (I assume that's how it works, either way it works flawlessly).

Does linux somehow do handle sql differently? maybe pyodbc is different for linux?

I've even tried converting it to a timestamp first and it still doesn't work. Maybe its complaining about something being returned in my query? But the query takes a while to run and this fails immediately.

It is pointed to the save exact DB2 Server on both machines. Everything I can think of is the same between the machines.

Comment: Is the same database server in both machines or there are independent instances?

Comment: @GustavoTopete The same instance

Comment: what about '2018-06-11' instead of '2018-6-11' ?

Comment: What happens if you instead do `SELECT '2018-6-11'::TIMESTAMP`?  That would tell you if the problem lies in recasting the date string.

Comment: @hootnot I get the same error.

Comment: @user1071847 I tried that instead and it printed out '2018-06-11' many times

Comment: @LegitStack:  Many times?  It should only print it once.  Then again, from my vague recollection of DB2, the query is probably something like `SELECT '2018-6-11'::TIMESTAMP FROM some_dummy_table` (I'm used to postgre).

Comment: @LegitStack:  What happens if you just run the query directly on the "bad" machine, without doing it through Python?  (Using a command-line client.)

Comment: @user1071847, I'll have to figure out how to do it through the command line, but it printed out many times because there are many rows in the table

Comment: what about: `... where time_stamp >=  date('2018-6-11')` ?